# toggle button doesn't remove class properly

Tags: javascript, toggle

Can anyone help with this javascript?

I would like to use toggle button to show and hide some DIVs.

When clicking the button(with `#sidebarCollapse`)first, I want it to display 2 divs named `#sidebar` and `.overlay` and when clicking the same button (with `#sidebarCollapse`) for the second time, it will remove the class from the above 2 divs (`#sidebar` .active  / `.overlay` .active)

I set the css right but don't know how to use javascript.

Please take a look at the following javascript, it doesn't remove `.overlay` `.active` class when I click the button (with `#sidebarCollapse`) for the second time.

Would you help with this?

Thank you very much in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
         $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
         $('.overlay').addClass('active');
         $(this).toggleClass('active');
     });

     $('.overlay').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
        $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
        $(this).removeClass('active');

     });
 });
```

Comment: sidebar collapse will only ever add a class to overlay, you should use toggleClass if you also want to take it off.  Also in your overlay click, you don't need the last line as the line before will handle that (as `this` will be part of the overlay collection)

Comment: Thanks Pete, this works perfectly!!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :)